# how to run a script in postun section in spec file

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I have a spec file with some content. There is also a script:

```
%postun
  if [ '$1' == 0 ]; then
    do some things
  fi
```

I want that a script in %postun section has been executed after package removed. But in $1 variable i receive a path (../../source/) instead of a number.

How can i receive a number instead a path?

Answer (score 0):

First - single quote means do not expand variables. Use double quotes:

```
if [ "$1" == 0 ]; then
```

I guess that your scriptlet looks like:

```
%postun
  if [ '$1' == 0 ]; then
    ./some-script.sh foo
  fi
```

Mind that $1 in the script is the `foo` and not the $1 from the scriptlet.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! A problem is that instead of 1 or 0 i have received "../../source" value in $1 variable in %postun section. And i do not know why is that?